# Error de identificador inválido al usar RIGHT JOIN dentro de cláusula FROM

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Quiero usar dentro de un `FROM` un subconjunto de 2 tablas usando `RIGHT JOIN` (quiero de ese subconjunto todas las filas de `ITV2_VEHICULOS` cuyo ID no esté en `ITV2_HIST_VEHICULOS`) para que el `SELECT` "tome" los datos de ahí y con el `WHERE` pueda filtrar (no sé si es una barbaridad lo que digo, en mi mente lo veo :D)

Mi query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ITV2_INSPECCIONES I,
    ITV2_HORAS_INSPECCION HI_FIN,
    ITV2_INSPECCIONES I_SIG,
    ITV2_HORAS_INSPECCION HI_SIG_INI,
    ITV2_HIST_VEHICULOS VH,
    ITV2_CATEGORIAS_VEHICULO CAT,
    ITV2_CLASIF_VEH_CONS CVC,
    ITV2_CLASIF_VEH_USO CVU,
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            ITV2_HIST_VEHICULOS VH
        RIGHT JOIN ITV2_VEHICULOS V ON
            VH.C_VEHICULO_ID = V.C_VEHICULO_ID
    ) VI 

WHERE
    I.C_TIPO_INSPECCION = 1     
    AND I.F_DESFAVORABLE IS NOT NULL
    AND I.C_RESULTADO IN(
        3,
        4
    )
    AND I.C_VEHICULO_ID = VI.C_VEHICULO_ID 
    AND VI.C_CATEGORIA_ID = CAT.C_CATEGORIA_ID
    AND VI.C_CLASIF_VEH_CONS_ID = CVC.C_CLASIF_VEH_CONS_ID
    AND VI.C_CLASIF_VEH_USO_ID = CVU.C_CLASIF_VEH_USO_ID -- HORAS  
    AND I.C_ESTACION_ID = HI_FIN.C_ESTACION_ID
    AND I.C_INSPECCION_ID = HI_FIN.C_INSPECCION_ID
    AND I.N_ANNO = HI_FIN.N_ANNO
    AND HI_FIN.C_TIPO_HORA_ID = 6 -- INSPECCION SIGUIENTE   
    AND I.C_ESTACION_ID = I_SIG.C_ESTACION_ID_FASE_ANT
    AND I.C_INSPECCION_ID = I_SIG.C_INSPECCION_ID_FASE_ANT
    AND I.N_ANNO = I_SIG.N_ANNO_FASE_ANT --    
    AND I_SIG.N_ANNO IN(
        2013,
        2014,
        2015,
        2016,
        2017,
        2018
    )
    AND I_SIG.C_ESTACION_ID IN(
        3,
        21,
        22,
        26,
        28,
        32,
        34,
        37,
        41,
        47,
        53,
        59,
        60
    )
    AND I_SIG.F_INSPECCION >= '01/09/2015'
    AND I_SIG.F_INSPECCION <= '30/09/2018' --

    AND I_SIG.F_DESFAVORABLE IS NULL
    AND I_SIG.C_RESULTADO IN(
        1,
        2
    ) -- Y HORAS

    AND I_SIG.C_ESTACION_ID = HI_SIG_INI.C_ESTACION_ID
    AND I_SIG.C_INSPECCION_ID = HI_SIG_INI.C_INSPECCION_ID
    AND I_SIG.N_ANNO = HI_SIG_INI.N_ANNO
    AND HI_SIG_INI.C_TIPO_HORA_ID = 1

 --GROUP BY...
```

Se me ocurrió que en vez de usar un `RIGHT JOIN` usar un `MINUS`, pero no hago bien los cruces en los `WHERE` porque me sale un solo resultado, 
quedando algo así:

```
SELECT *
                    FROM
                           ITV2_INSPECCIONES I
                           , ITV2_HORAS_INSPECCION HI_FIN
                           , ITV2_INSPECCIONES I_SIG
                           , ITV2_HORAS_INSPECCION HI_SIG_INI              
                           , (SELECT * FROM(
                                SELECT V.C_VEHICULO_ID AS VEHICULO_ID, V.C_CATEGORIA_ID AS C_CATEGORIA_ID,V.C_CLASIF_VEH_CONS_ID AS C_CLASIF_VEH_CONS_ID,V.C_CLASIF_VEH_USO_ID AS C_CLASIF_VEH_USO_ID FROM ITV2_VEHICULOS V
                                MINUS
                                SELECT HV.C_VEHICULO_ID,HV.C_CATEGORIA_ID,HV.C_CLASIF_VEH_CONS_ID, HV.C_CLASIF_VEH_USO_ID FROM ITV2_HIST_VEHICULOS HV
                                )) VI       
                           , ITV2_CATEGORIAS_VEHICULO CAT
                           , ITV2_CLASIF_VEH_CONS CVC
                           , ITV2_CLASIF_VEH_USO CVU
                    WHERE               
                           I.C_TIPO_INSPECCION = 1
                           --AND I.N_FASE = 1
                           AND I.F_DESFAVORABLE IS NOT NULL
                           AND I.C_RESULTADO IN (3, 4)
                           AND VI.VEHICULO_ID = I.C_VEHICULO_ID   -- SIMPLIFICACIÓN (VER SI VEHÍCULO HISTORIFICADO)
                           -- CATEGORÍAS RARAS
                           AND VI.C_CATEGORIA_ID = CAT.C_CATEGORIA_ID
                           AND VI.C_CLASIF_VEH_CONS_ID = CVC.C_CLASIF_VEH_CONS_ID
                           AND VI.C_CLASIF_VEH_USO_ID = CVU.C_CLASIF_VEH_USO_ID
                           -- HORAS
                           AND I.C_ESTACION_ID = HI_FIN.C_ESTACION_ID 
                           AND I.C_INSPECCION_ID = HI_FIN.C_INSPECCION_ID
                           AND I.N_ANNO = HI_FIN.N_ANNO
                           AND HI_FIN.C_TIPO_HORA_ID = 6
                           -- INSPECCION SIGUIENTE
                           AND I.C_ESTACION_ID = I_SIG.C_ESTACION_ID_FASE_ANT 
                           AND I.C_INSPECCION_ID = I_SIG.C_INSPECCION_ID_FASE_ANT
                           AND I.N_ANNO = I_SIG.N_ANNO_FASE_ANT
                           --
                           AND I_SIG.N_ANNO IN (2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018)
                           AND I_SIG.C_ESTACION_ID IN (3,21,22,26,28,32,34,37,41,47,53,59,60)
                           AND I_SIG.F_INSPECCION >= '01/09/2015'
                           AND I_SIG.F_INSPECCION <= '30/09/2018'
                           --
                           AND I_SIG.F_DESFAVORABLE IS NULL
                           AND I_SIG.C_RESULTADO IN (1, 2)
                           -- Y HORAS
                           AND I_SIG.C_ESTACION_ID = HI_SIG_INI.C_ESTACION_ID 
                           AND I_SIG.C_INSPECCION_ID = HI_SIG_INI.C_INSPECCION_ID
                           AND I_SIG.N_ANNO = HI_SIG_INI.N_ANNO
                           AND HI_SIG_INI.C_TIPO_HORA_ID = 1
```

"Huelo" la solución pero no la alcanzo, me muestra sólo la primera fila de todas las que me tiene que mostrar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo que lo que quieres es traer los datos de `ITV2_VEHICULOS` cuyo ID no esté en `ITV2_HIST_VEHICULOS` por lo cual no necesitas hacer JOIN entre estas tablas ya que nunca podrás usar campos de `ITV2_HIST_VEHICULOS` ya que no existe match en el historico. Lo que te recomiendo es que en el `FROM` dejes solo `ITV2_VEHICULOS` y en el `WHERE` incluyas `AND NOT VI.C_VEHICULO_ID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT C_VEHICULO_ID FROM ITV2_HIST_VEHICULOS)`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ITV2_INSPECCIONES I,
    ITV2_HORAS_INSPECCION HI_FIN,
    ITV2_INSPECCIONES I_SIG,
    ITV2_HORAS_INSPECCION HI_SIG_INI,
    ITV2_HIST_VEHICULOS VH,
    ITV2_CATEGORIAS_VEHICULO CAT,
    ITV2_CLASIF_VEH_CONS CVC,
    ITV2_CLASIF_VEH_USO CVU,
    ITV2_VEHICULOS VI   
WHERE
    I.C_TIPO_INSPECCION = 1     
    AND I.F_DESFAVORABLE IS NOT NULL
    AND I.C_RESULTADO IN(
        3,
        4
    )
    AND I.C_VEHICULO_ID = VI.C_VEHICULO_ID 
    AND VI.C_CATEGORIA_ID = CAT.C_CATEGORIA_ID
    AND VI.C_CLASIF_VEH_CONS_ID = CVC.C_CLASIF_VEH_CONS_ID
    AND VI.C_CLASIF_VEH_USO_ID = CVU.C_CLASIF_VEH_USO_ID -- HORAS  
    AND I.C_ESTACION_ID = HI_FIN.C_ESTACION_ID
    AND I.C_INSPECCION_ID = HI_FIN.C_INSPECCION_ID
    AND I.N_ANNO = HI_FIN.N_ANNO
    AND HI_FIN.C_TIPO_HORA_ID = 6 -- INSPECCION SIGUIENTE   
    AND I.C_ESTACION_ID = I_SIG.C_ESTACION_ID_FASE_ANT
    AND I.C_INSPECCION_ID = I_SIG.C_INSPECCION_ID_FASE_ANT
    AND I.N_ANNO = I_SIG.N_ANNO_FASE_ANT --    
    AND I_SIG.N_ANNO IN(
        2013,
        2014,
        2015,
        2016,
        2017,
        2018
    )
    AND I_SIG.C_ESTACION_ID IN(
        3,
        21,
        22,
        26,
        28,
        32,
        34,
        37,
        41,
        47,
        53,
        59,
        60
    )
    AND I_SIG.F_INSPECCION >= '01/09/2015'
    AND I_SIG.F_INSPECCION <= '30/09/2018' --

    AND I_SIG.F_DESFAVORABLE IS NULL
    AND I_SIG.C_RESULTADO IN(
        1,
        2
    ) -- Y HORAS

    AND I_SIG.C_ESTACION_ID = HI_SIG_INI.C_ESTACION_ID
    AND I_SIG.C_INSPECCION_ID = HI_SIG_INI.C_INSPECCION_ID
    AND I_SIG.N_ANNO = HI_SIG_INI.N_ANNO
    AND HI_SIG_INI.C_TIPO_HORA_ID = 1
    AND NOT VI.C_VEHICULO_ID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT C_VEHICULO_ID FROM ITV2_HIST_VEHICULOS)

 --GROUP BY...
```

Comment: Obtengo 0 registros, he editado mi pregunta añadiendo más info. Gracias por colaborar

Comment: Me lié con las tablas, efectivamente debía devolverme 0 registros, la consulta es correcta.